# Expression pour désigner quelqu'un qui doit faire toutes les tâches restantes

Tags: vocabulaire

Bonjour,

Je cherche une expression pour désigner une personne ou un groupe de personnes qui doit (ou doivent) faire toutes les tâches restantes (celles qui n'ont pas encore été assignées) parmi des tâches à faire (soit par obligation ou de manière volontaire).

J'ai pensé à bouche-trou, mais ça sonne un peu péjoratif et je ne suis pas sûr si le mot englobe bien mon idée.

Merci pour vos suggestions

Comment: équipe de "nettoyage"?

Comment: C'est pas exactement cela, mais selon le contexte, "L'équipe d'astreinte" pourrait peut-être fonctionner ?

Comment: «nettoyage» -> Dans le contexte, pas tout à fait. C'est un détail que j'ai oublié d'inclure dans ma question, mais ce sont plutôt des tâches à long terme. Mais merci quand même pour la suggestion!

Comment: «astreinte» -> Vous me faites apprendre un nouveau mot, merci! Mais d'après ce que je vois en ligne, c'est plutôt une obligation stricte ou une sanction, donc c'est un peu trop fort pour ce que je recherche.

Comment: peut-être «équipe subsidiaire» , «personnel subsidiaire» ou encore "personnel auxiliaire"

Comment: [ jouer le rôle de la ] *La voiture balai*, celle qui embarque les coureurs du Tour de France qui sont trop en retard pour terminer les temps, ou, les agents qui nettoient les rues derrière les derniers manifestants qui défilent. — *L'équipe de finisseurs*

Answer (score 1):

Je propose : Factotum. On pourrait d'ailleurs dire que c'est étymologiquement le contraire d'un préposé.